# Open an photo with external gallery-app and browse photos of directory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

In my gallery-app i can list all photos of a selected directory. When i click on one of the photos i call the following function:

```
private fun play(photoFile: File) {
    Intent().apply {            
        val mimeType = MediaUtils.MIME_TYPE_IMAGE
        action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        setDataAndType(Uri.parse(photoFile.absolutePath), mimeType)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
        flags += Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        val packageManager = mainActivity.packageManager
        val activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(this, 0)
        val isIntentSafe = activities.size > 0
        if (isIntentSafe) {
            mainActivity.startActivity(this)
        } else {               
            log.e("""The video "$mediaPath/${mediaItem.name}" could not be played""")
        }
    }
}
```

This function opens the selected photo in the selected image viewer so that i can see the photo correctly. But in contrary to other galleries that i installed, i am not able to swipe to the next or previous photo inside the image viewer. If i want to see the next photo in my app, i have to navigate back to the overview and then click the next one. How can i tell the opening gallery to enable its navigation for the current directory?

Comment: Are you using an old Android device? Your code should not even run from Android N on as you would get a FileUriExposedException then.

Comment: I am using Google Pixel 3a

Comment: That is not the info i asked for as how would i know which Android version it used?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by replacing this line

```
setDataAndType(Uri.parse(photoFile.absolutePath), mimeType)
```

with this one

```
setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(photoFile), mimeType)
```